# Making image responsive: Using ReactJS and Sanity BlockContent

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive, sanity

```
<BlockContent
  blocks={post.body}
  imageOptions={{ width: 800, height: 400}}
  serializers={serializers}
/>
```

So I have this imageOptions prop which takes css styles, I can use only pixels but I cannot put percentages as it is crashing, I want to be able to make the image full width, both the image itself and the container it is inside. but when I use the pixel values, it is cropping the image which I dont want. How can I make this responsive, I have width, height, maxheight and maxwith to use, I am not sure if imageOptions prop supporst anything else.

Comment: Have you found the answer to this problem yet?

Comment: Yes I did.. It was long ago so I don't remember exactly what I did but I remember I wrapped the BlockContent inside a div and made that responsive... in the image Options I probably made width and height auto or 100%

Answer (score 0):

Using css was able to fix the issue

```
figure img {
    width: 100%;
}
```